# How to detect percentage of clouds after applying SLIC as below?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to calculate the percentage of cloud cover. How to calculate it after the image being segmented using SLIC? Can anybody help ?

```
segments_slic = slic(img, n_segments=250, compactness=10, sigma=1)
print("Slic number of segments: %d" % len(np.unique(segments_slic)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think you don't need to apply SLIC for this. Basic thresholding can be used to find the percentage of cloud cover on a grayscale image as the clouds are white and will have a greater pixel values.

[image: test image]

I used this image as a test image.

```
img = cv2.imread('cloud.png', 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('image', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This gives

[image: thresholded image]

So we need to add all these values where there is a white pixel to find total number of white pixels. Instead of the thresholded pixel values to 255 we change it to 1 so that we can simply add them. You can read more on [thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-alpha/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html) here. Then we calculate its sum and divide it by width and height and multiply by 100 to obtain the percentage.

```
img = cv2.imread('cloud.png', 0)
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
total = sum(map(sum, thresh)) # to find total sum of 2D array thresh
percent = total/height/width*100
print('percentage of cloud cover is =', percent, '%')
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help !

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.